# How to import an async function and use await -- error Unexpected reserved word 'await'

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, async-await

I have a file that exports an async function, like this

```
// api.js


import { getInfo } from "somewhere";

export async function getSomething() {
  await getInfo()
}
```

and then I'm trying to import it into another file like this.

```
// Dashboard.vue


import { getSomething } from "./api.js";

async created() {
    await getSomething()
  },
```

but I'm getting this error

```
Syntax Error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'. (77:26)
 77 | await getSomething()
```

Of course, this is all pseudo-code but the problem is -- why does my file not recognize the imported method as an async call? Is there a different way to import something when it is an async method?

edit: perhaps my code is not giving enough context, so here is a better example of how I'm consuming the async method

```
<template>
  <div>Hello world</div>
</template>

<script>
import { getSomething } from "./api";

export default {
  methods: {
     async init() {
        await getSomething()
    }
  },
  async created() {
    await this.init()
  }
};
</script>
```

here is an exact view of the compile failure. `getAssessment` === `getSomething` in my example above

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                              1:29:06 AM

 error  in ./src/components/Dashboard.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

Syntax Error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'. (79:26)

  77 |       if (user) {
  78 |         this.user = user;
> 79 |         this.assessment = await getAssessment();
     |                           ^
  80 |       }
```

Comment: the problem is purely in the second file, nothing to do with the first file - the syntax you show in the second file doesn't look correct at all

Comment: ok, can you tell me how? this is a .vue file -- it's pretty standard. but it is possible I'm missing something.

Comment: what you're missing is context - if your second file is exactly as shown then it's wrong ... but no idea how to help, since there's no context for the code you posted

Comment: I mean... it's a large file. I didn't want to post the entire thing, but I guess i can. I'm calling the imported function inside the created lifecycle method. but i could call it in a function i create in my Methods object as well. it doesn't matter where i call it from, it's still telling me that await is a reserved word.

Comment: @Bravo I have updated my example to show more clearly how I'm doing this. the same error still applies.

Comment: that's good, that's enough context to tell you that it should work - I use that type of code in about 20 views in my PWA - except I never make created or mounted `async`, i.e. I do `created() { this.init(); }` because I never need to await in created myself - but that's just me - it shouldn't be the issue - though, perhaps it is - try without async/await on `created` function

Comment: I mean... I think it should work too! but it isn't.. The issue is not that it's in a created or init method. I can write a completely different method and try to call it from the template and it still doesn't let me use `await`

Comment: that's completely weird then ... works fine in vue@2.6.14 - can you post more details about the error - is it runtime or "compile" time?

Comment: it is compile, and i have updated above

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] please, not just pseudo code?

Comment: is line 79 directly inside an `async` function ... i.e. not in a non-async callback for example -in other words, please show the whole function that line 79 is in

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// api.js

import { getInfo } from 'somewhere'

export const getSomething = async () => {
    return await getInfo();
}


// another file

import { getSomething } from './api.js'

const created = async () => {
  await getSomething();
}

created();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work